# what is the relation between ASCII and the result shown (a)?

Tags: c, ascii

In the first session of algorithm class , the professor asked us to spot the errors and explain the reason behind the letter a shown as a result . The answer has something with ASCII code but I did not get it

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char var=353;
printf("%c",var);
return 0;

}
```

`

Comment: A `char` is an 8-bit-value. But 353 is above the 255 limit, so the interpretation/handling depends on the compiler.

Comment: @zx485 thank you for you answer but I want to know why does it show the character a specifically  when executed ? what does it have to do with 353 ?

Comment: It's overflowing, so it's interpreted as `353 % 256 == 97`, which is the ASCII code for `a`.

Comment: Signed integer overflow yields *Undefined Behavior*, anything can happen. (on those systems where `char` is `unsigned` the value would simply be reduced `modulo 256`). What do you think it should print ? [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/) ? Note: anything above 127 depends on the terminal and supported terminal character set.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin there's no integer overflow here, since there are no arithmetic operations. The code in the question is an out-of-range assignment

Comment: @M.M - the result would still be implementation defined. [6.2.5 Types(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p3)

Comment: Need to know `CHAR_BIT` from your system's `<limits.h>`. (The error is that someone wrote code that others can't understand. Also, just about any mention of ASCII is an inacurracy.)

Answer (score 2):

If `char` defaults to `unsigned` in your implementation, and `char` is 8 bits, then

```
char var = 353;
```

is equivalent to

```
char var = (353 % 256);
```

and the value of that modulus expression is `97`. That's the ASCII code for `a`.

If `char` defaults to `signed char`, the code produces implementation-defined behavior because 353 is too large. If you're still getting `a`, it's because the implementation happens to be using the same modular arithmetic when signed integer overflow occurs, which is common. But you shouldn't depend on it, since it's implementation-specific.

Comment: It's implementation-defined behaviour due to out-of-range assignment. There is no overflow nor UB.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to view things in hex sometimes. The decimal value 353 is hex 0x161. Since a `char` is an 8-bit value, that means it can only hold numbers up to 0xff, or decimal 255 (unsigned) or 127 (signed). Well, clearly 0x161 can't fit into a data type that can only count to 0xff, so the compiler truncated the upper bits to make it fit. The result was the value ended up being 0x61, which is decimal 97, which is the letter `a` in ASCII.

Comment: So I have another issue if I put 353 between ' ' only one digit is shown and also when I put %3c  this is the result --3 . What's the explanation ?

Comment: @joon Putting it in a single quote turns it into a `char` constant. In other words, it changes it from the value 353 to the character `3`. It's not a valid thing to do.